# Jackson polymorphism issue, unable to deserialize base class

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to use polymorphic deserialization to deserialize some JSON to a subclass of a Base class. Here is my code:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NONE)
@JsonSubTypes({ @Type(value = SubClass1.class, name = "SubClass1"), @Type(value =  
SubClass2.class, name = "SubClass2") })
public abstract class AbstractClass {

   private String commonField1;
   private CommonObject commonField2;
   private String commonField3;

public class SubClass1 extends AbstractClass {
    private List<String> listOfFields;
}

public class SubClass2 extends AbstractClass {
    private Map<String, Integer> stringintmap;
}
```

My subclass JSON examples

Deserialization process which fails

```
objectmapper.readValue(subclassJson, AbstractClass.class);
```

This throws JsonMappingException: cannot construct instance of BaseClass.

Comment: You are not indicating the type of the serialized subclass. You should try something like `@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@class")` instead of `@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NONE)`.

Comment: Hi @blafasel that was the first solution i tried but i got the following exception

Unexpected token (END_OBJECT), expected FIELD_NAME: missing property '@class' that is to contain type id  (for class com.blah.blah.AbstractClass.

Comment: Also @blafasel. Also you mentioned "You are not indicating the type of the serialized subclass". How am i supposed to do this? I do not know which type i'll be deserialising until runtime. Therefore i pass in the BaseClass to the object mapper's readValue(... ) method. As i understand it the JsonSubTypes annotation should register the subclasses with Jackson as sub class implementations right?

Comment: The `missing property '@class'` is expected if you try to deserialize a JSON-string that was produced by the code containing `@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NONE)`. If you produce your JSON with `@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@class")`, then I would expect your JSON to read like ` ... '@class':'SubClass1' ...` and this should work.

Comment: @blafasel shouldn't those be answers?